# grape api endpoint "Not Found" even though I tried to define it

Tags: ruby, rspec, rack, ruby-grape

When I test `/api/ping` it works as expected outputting `"PONG"`. However I expect a JSON response for `/api/users/:user_id` but it comes up not found, and the before block in the namespace is not called.

```
class Users < Grape::API
  namespace ':user_id' do
    before do
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end

    get do
      @user
    end
  end
end

class API < Grape::API
  format :json
  default_format :json
  prefix 'api'

  get 'ping' do
    'PONG'
  end

  mount Users => 'users'
end
```

And in the rspec test:

```
let(:user) { create(:user) }
before { get "/api/users/#{user.id}" }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Grape documentation suggests it is valid, I could not make your example work using `mount GrapeSubClass => 'prefix'` syntax at all, and gave up.

However, if I make the following simple change to your main API class, all seems to work:

```
class API < Grape::API
  format :json
  default_format :json
  prefix 'api'

  get 'ping' do
    'PONG'
  end

  # mount second API class in a namespace
  namespace 'users' do
    mount Users
  end
end
```